# Using socket.io to add chat functionality in NodeJS Application

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have created a NodeJS server which have  6 different end points and all these endpoints perform basic CRUD operation on my SQL Database. Now I need to create a Chat functionality on this server which should be hosted on the 9th endpoint of the same server (as the chat also needs to perform few CRUD operation with the same SQL server)

Below is my project structure:

```
> bin
   - www
>js
   - common JS files
>node_modules
   - all node dependencies
>routes
   - endpoint_1
   - endpoint_2
   - endpoint_3
   - endpoint_4
   - endpoint_5
   - endpoint_6
   - chatEndPoint
- app.js
```

I have gone through the Chat Application Demo as show [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaMsKXQSUJE) and the source code mention [HERE](https://github.com/sreejesh79/android-socket.io-server-demo).

But [this source code](https://github.com/sreejesh79/android-socket.io-server-demo/blob/master/index.js) work only when I have chatting functionality but now I have a different project structure and I am not able to run the application correctly.

I am not sure how do i manage the dependencies and implementation

Where do I place the following code: (with respect to my project structure)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Where do i paste the code for handling connections and chat msgs:

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('one user connected '+socket.id);
    socket.on('message',function(data){
        var sockets = io.sockets.sockets;
        /*sockets.forEach(function(sock){
            if(sock.id != socket.id)
            {
                sock.emit('message',data);
            }
        })*/
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
    })
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('one user disconnected '+socket.id);
    })
})
```

And my server is already running on a port (3881) so do I need to listen on a different port for this chat functionality.

How do I configure my `app.js` file for consume and route my `/chatEndPoint`?

Answer (score 0):

This needs to go at the very top of your app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

The io.on.connection function goes after all of your routing in app.js, and all your socket functions go inside of it. Read [This](http://socket.io/docs/) for setting up socket.io. Also I would suggest having a package.json file in your root directory. See [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json). And no, you should not need to change the port. I would also suggest making a views folder in your root, store your html files here. If you have seperate .js files for your routes store those in routes folder.